# Can I make a GSuite Add-On that is shared with domain users AND collaborators

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-workspace, google-apps-script-addon

So I have made an Add-On for Google Docs. I have published it tied to our GSuite domain, as this is only intended for our own use. When I install this add-on, it is visible to our domain users. The problem is, we have many collaborators on our documents who are not part of our domain. I understood the docs that if an add-on has been enabled on a document, all collaborators can access it, but this doesn't seem to apply for users who are collaborators but not on the same domain.

Is there any way I can create an add-on that is also seen by collaborators outside my organization?

Answer (score 0):

you have published an add-on tied to your G Suite domain.
If you have access to the stand alone script, it may be possible create a test on a preview document and share it with others. i have tied a picture to explain it.

[this picture explain how to enable an add-on publicly and privately on a test document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUcjl.png)